# what does "\ " mean in R regular expression?

Tags: r

```
"hallo\ nworld"=="hallo nworld"
[1] TRUE
```

In R, `\+blank` =`blank` ? what is the meaning of this kind of grammar?

Answer (score 2):

In R regex there are some metacharacters (like `. \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?`) which have special meanings, for example `.` matchs a single character, `+` means the preceding item will be matched one or more items.

```
> grep("a+", c("abc.", "def", "cba a", "a.a", "a+"), value=TRUE)
[1] "abc."  "cba a" "a.a"   "a+"
```

In this example `a+` means we want to match the string which has one or more `a` within it

If you want to match the string which has an actual `+` character within it(like the last string `a+` in above case), you should use the backslash `\` in your regex to make the parser interpret it differently (otherwise it would be interpreted using its special meaning), so the above example would change to:

```
> grep("a\\+", c("abc.", "def", "cba a", "a.a", "a+"), value=TRUE)
[1] "a+"
```

Note that we have `\\` before `+` since `\` itself is a metacharacter, so you need one `\` for `+`, and one `\` for `\` itself

When you use backslash before non-metacharacters, its meaning is implementation-dependent, like `\a` is interpreted as `BEL`, `\t` as `TAB`, `\r` as `CR`. In your case you preceded a space with `\` and it's interpreted still as space.

although `\+` is not defined as an escape sequence, as I tested below:

```
> str <- "hello,\+world"
Error: '\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""hello,\+"
```

So if you want to use `+` in literal string you use `+` directly, if you want to use it in regex, you use `+` directly as repetition quantifier or you use the escape sequence `\\+`

I found the two links [Regular Expressions as used in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html), [Regular Expression with The R Language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) useful, you can find more details there

Answer (score 1):

\ is an escape character.  It changes the meaning of the following character, although in the case of a space, it doesn't change anything.  If you do '\t' you get a tab character, if you use '\n' you get a newline.  \ will only work on certain characters, and all other characters it will just match them.  If you want to include a '\' in your output, you need to use `\\`

Here's some other uses of the backslash character in regular expressions:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html